# Bootstrap 3 Progress Bar set Text when transition is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have a bootstrap progress bar here:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning six-sec-ease-in-out" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="100" aria-label="0"></div>
</div>
```

The six-sec-ease-in-out class is just there to prolong the transition and that code is over here: (not sure if it affects this or not - don't think it does)

```
.six-sec-ease-in-out {
  -webkit-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 6s ease-in-out;
}
```

And here's my JS just to keep the text centered:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.progress .progress-bar').progressbar({ display_text: 'center' });    
    });
</script>
```

My Question:

How do I change the progress text from the percentage to something like "The task is completed" when the transition is complete (i.e. 100% completed has been reached)?

I'm assuming I use javascript to do this but I have no idea what methods I should use.  I'm currently using the latest bootstrap progress bar which is v0.8.5 using bootstrap 3.3.4.

**Edit 1:**

As requested, here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12460/
(not too familiar with using JSFiddle)

**Edit 2:**

Ad requested, here's a link to the plugin I'm using: http://www.minddust.com/project/bootstrap-progressbar/

Comment: Could you provide us with a Fiddle so that we can test it for you?

Comment: Kindly provide an example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Added an example, see edit

Comment: Can you provide link to progress bar plugin you are using?

Comment: @Barry, does the page reload to show the updated progress ? I am thinking that you could use jQuery `.attr`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao, see edit 2

Comment: @andre3wap, the page does not reload when the transition is completed

Comment: @BarryDoyle I've added answer with demo.. You can check it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/DTcHh/12466/)** and **[Doc](https://github.com/minddust/bootstrap-progressbar#done)**

You can make use of `done` option where you can have `callback function` to update the `text` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.progress .progress-bar').progressbar({
       display_text: 'center',
       done:function(){ //use this option
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".progressbar-front-text").text("The task is completed");
        },100);//small amount of time to render html 100ms infact
       }
   });    
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)